# Find all values for prime $p$, so that $x^2+px-330p=0$ only has one positive integral root.

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

After studying the problem, I found that the sum of the root is $-p$ and the product of them is $-330p$. Does this help?

Comment: By [Einsenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), your polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ unless $p^2 | 330p \iff p | 330 \implies p = 2, 3, 5 \text{ or } 11$. You have only 4 primes to check.

Comment: @achillehui Nice use of Eisenstein!

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the roots is $-p$. Suppose the positive root is $a$, then the negative root is $-p-a$

The product of the roots is $-a(p+a)=-330p$

Now either $p|a$ or $p|(p+a)$ (because $p$ is prime) which also implies $p|a$ so let $a=pb$ then $$pb(pb+p)=330p$$ so that $$pb(b+1)=330$$

And you can go from there ...

Comment: You works do not involve the sum, so why wrote it?

Comment: @user139024 My first statement is "The sum of the roots is $-p$" - I then choose expressions for the two roots which ensure this is the case. Once I have done that I use those expressions to consider the product. I don't need to refer to the sum again, because any solution I find is constrained to meet the condition on the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

The quadratic $\;x^2+px-330p\;$ has one single (real) root iff its discriminant is zero:

$$\Delta:=b^2-4ac=p^2+1320p=0\iff\;\ldots$$

Now what's the condition(s) that make(s) sure the root is positive?

**Another way:**

The above quadratic has one single root iff it is a perfect square, so let us complete the square:

$$x^2+px-330p=\left(x+\frac p2\right)^2-\frac{p^2}4-330p\;\implies\;\text{it has to be that}$$

$$\frac{p^2}4+330p=0\iff p^2+1320p=0$$

and we get the same as above...

Comment: Of course @T.Bongers, thanks. Edited

Comment: Only one root has to be positive, from the equation

Comment: Why "has to", @user139024 ?

Comment: The equation predetermined the signs of the roots

Comment: The equation satisfies the conditions if it has two different roots one of which is positive and the other negative.

Comment: Bennett, could you figure out values for p, from the sum and products of the roots

Comment: Neither of the solutions here for $p$ is a positive integer - indeed since the sum of the roots is negative for $p$ positive, the answer cannot be a double root.

Comment: Well @MarkBennet, perhaps $\;p<0\;$ ...? After all, primes in the ring $\;\Bbb Z\;$ don't have to be positive.

Comment: True, and that if that possibility is taken into account there are a couple more solutions to add to the two with positive $p$.

Answer (score 1):

you need to solve the equation $b^2-4ac=0$, $\Rightarrow p^2+1320p=0$, so $p=0$ or $-1320$, then the root would be $-b=-p=1320$ which is positive.

We reject $p=0$ as it does not give us a positive root.

But then $p$ is not prime..

Comment: P is a prime...

Comment: I just mean if we let p=-1320, then it is not prime